# Bixolon SPP-R200 command to scroll to black mark

Tags: bluetooth, thermal-printer, escpos

I have a Bixolon SPP-R200 (and an SPP-R200III). I've set the printer to Label Mode. I'm able to print using Standard Mode and the user can move to the top of the next ticket by pressing the feed button on the printer.

Is there a command I can send (via Bluetooth) to do this on behalf of the user? I can send `LF` - but this behaves as expected, moving the paper by one line height.

According to an ESC POS document I found online, `GS FF` would be what I want. But that's not a command available to the R200 or the Mark III.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: I'd assume that sending a formfeed (FF), hex 0C, feeds one label.

Comment: When I try using `FF` in Label Mode it advances the paper by a set height (presumably configurable). However, it does not appear to use the sensor - whether I use Standard Mode or Page Mode

Comment: The printers command manual lists a few commands to calibrate and setup the black mark sensor.  Lacking of that specific printer I fear I can only be of limited help here.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing the other day. I thought I'd tested `FF` in Standard Mode but obviously I hadn't - because it works. I must have been in Page Mode - `FF` and `ESC FF` both cause the printer to scroll to a set height in this mode

Comment: @Mitkins did you finally get a solution yet, can you share?